# OpenLayers popups remain visible on map, after refresh

Tags: javascript, popup, openlayers

I am adding popups for some items on a map. I refresh the elements every 30 seconds.
Here is the problem:

- I hover one element and leave the mouse right there until the refresh
- when I move the mouse away, the popup content is still there (it disappears only on zoom in/out, or if i drag the map)

I tried removing the entire layer and adding it again, deleting all markers, but no change.

Are popups cached somehow? 
Can this be a OpenLayers bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want in the refresh event handler to close yourself any popups.

There are accessible through `map.popups` and use something like `toggle` or `destroy` or `hide` (depending on your needs) on each of them.

Comment: Thank you! I used hide for every popup on refresh (don't quite know why I didn't do this earlier)

Comment: @AlexandraChis Since hide may keep references (and so memory usage) you may prefer to use destroy if the popup isn't of any use anymore

Comment: I'm displaying a list of elements that can grow any time (that's why I keep refreshing it). I couldn't get why destroying the entire layer didn't work at first. I will try destroy and tell you how it worked.

Comment: @AlexandraChis As you can see, popups aren't referenced by layers but directly by the map. That's why it didn't work.